# Performance Counter : \Processor(_Total)\% Processor : Time Azure WAD Performance Counter

Tags: azure, cloud, performancecounter, azure-diagnostics

What does `\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time` mean. What are the underlying assumptions.

Description:
As this is a performance counter from WAD Performance Table counter; as this is Azure is there any assumption for measuring the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Azure counter is simply a recording of the Windows Performance Counter

> The simplest measure of a system's
>   busyness is Processor(_Total)\%
>   Processor Time, which measures the
>   total utilization of your processor by
>   all running processes. Note that if
>   you have a multiprocessor machine,
>   Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time
>   actually measures the average
>   processor utilization of your machine
>   (i.e. utilization averaged over all
>   processors).
>   from http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/key-performance-monitor-counters.html

In Azure, I believe this counter is calculated over a fairly short sampling interval on each VM - so if you collect the sample every 10 seconds, say, then the instantaneous measurement will only tell you what was occurring near to each measurement point - it won't necessarily reflect what was occurring inbetween measurements.

Comment: say if the values returns 0.594788764583333 , can I assume that the system is 59% busy...?

Comment: No - I think that means the CPU is 0.59% busy

Comment: I think it cant be 0.59 % as the OS itself will consume nearly 40% to 45% of the processing power...

Comment: you are correct. See this [MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/5c6d616a-8e85-4060-b861-9f0ac8e0ad7a/)